# "Always available offline" not showing in right click menu on Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, offline-files

Even after enabling the offline files/ sync center then "Always available offline" not showing in right click menu on Windows 11 when I click on a folder on local area network.

restarted multiple times as well but still not showing.

**`OS Version:    10.0.22000 N/A Build 22000`**

Comment: Where are the offline files? Are they physically local on your computer?

Comment: They are on a server on my local area network... I can work on those folders and files online but can't keep them offline. because don't see the option "Always available offline"  in right click menu.

Comment: You need to make a local copy on your machine that you can then sync and work offline.  You cannot work “offline “ on files that are only remote

Comment: Yes I want to make a copy but how to --- by selecting the option "Always available offline" in right click menu --- but that option is not showing in right click menu.

Comment: I am not sure what is wrong with your system as that option normally works.

Comment: Did you enable Offline Files?   Control Panel, Sync Center "Enable Offline Files.   This is not a right click, so you may not have Offline Files enabled.

Comment: Yes i already did that . it didn't resolve the problem then I disabled and enables again  and restarted the computer for 2/3 times but still not resolved.

Comment: Is your Windows 11 system Insider?  or Production?  Either way, it is not up to date.  Trying updating it.   Then run DISM / SFC   ....     (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: Try the registry modifications from [this article](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/163151-how-add-remove-always-available-offline-context-menu-windows.html) and reboot. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc I already tried this articles even before posting question to this website. now I will re-install windows.

Comment: Actually some days ago I uninstalled Microsoft Edge using `setup --uninstall --force-uninstall --system-level` command. may be this caused problem. I would reinstall windows.

Answer (score 1):

> OS Version:    10.0.22000 N/A Build 22000

Your Windows 11 version is a long (long) way behind. Failure in offline files is likely just a symptom of a bigger issue.

I suggest you back it up and reinstall Windows.

Consider if your machine is not properly Windows 11 compliant and return to and stay with Windows 10 until you can get a compliant machine.

If you believe the machine will run Windows 11, install Windows 11 and make sure you are up to 22621 which is now current.